# (SQL) How to average values with the same IDs

Tags: sql

I have sql code like this:

```
SELECT ID_song as ID, rate
FROM Songs
    JOIN Rating USING (ID_song)
order by ID_song;
```

Output is:

```
  ID ¦ rate  
 ----+------ 
  27 ¦ 10    
  28 ¦ 1     
  31 ¦ 4     
  31 ¦ 1     
  41 ¦ 7     
  41 ¦ 3     
  44 ¦ 1     
  44 ¦ 7
```

I want to average rate for duplicate IDs to have always one unique ID with its average value of rate like this:

Output is:

```
  ID ¦ rate  
 ----+------ 
  27 ¦ 10    
  28 ¦ 1     
  31 ¦ 2.5   
  41 ¦ 5     
  44 ¦ 4
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Is this question about SQL or HTML/CSS?  Because your question looks a lot like the former.

Comment: For future questions: please do not supply sample data as "runnable HTML", use plain text. Tools like http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/ can help you with that or just copy and paste from your SQL tool if that can return (formatted) plain text.

Answer (score 2):

For your query

```
SELECT ID_song as ID, AVG(rate)
FROM Songs
    JOIN Rating USING (ID_song)
GROUP BY ID_song
order by ID_song;
```

Example of `AVG()` And `Group By`

```
SELECT ID,AVG(rate) FROM Table1
GROUP BY ID
```

**Output**

```
ID  AVG(rate)
27  10
28  1
31  2.5
41  5
44  4
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c17ddc/1

Answer (score 0):

Just use avg and group by - given the using clause I've assumed oracle.

```
SELECT ID_song as ID, avg(rate)
FROM Songs
JOIN Rating USING (ID_song)
group by ID_song
order by ID_song;
```

Ideally use normal ansi syntax for joins and not the using syntax.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the average you use AVG()
And be sure to group by.

```
SELECT ID_song as ID, AVG(rate)
FROM Songs
    JOIN Rating USING (ID_song)
GROUP BY ID_song
order by ID_song;
```

Answer (score 0):

<

```
Select Distinct(Id_song) as ID, avg(rate)
from songs,rating
where song.Id_song = rating.Id_song
order by song.Id_song
```

>

(if you can share the two table structure it would be more helpful. I usually don't use joins. This way is more easy for me.just my opinion)